# Can't add items to linked list in a loop in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have started learning C++ and as a first project, I am trying to make a linked list application. I have not had any real problems with the linked list concept so far as I have previously worked with it in a different language.

So far, I already have working functions to add items to the list and to print it. In the main() class, I can add items one by one, but when I try to add multiple items via a for or while loop.

I have separate functions to create an item and to add it to (the beginning of) the list:

```
ListItem createItem(int value)
{
    ListItem x;
    std::cout << &x;
    x.value = value;

    return x;
}

void addBeg(ListItem* &start, ListItem &item)
{
    // Adding to an empty list
    if (start == nullptr)
    {
        item.prev = &item;
        item.next = &item;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << std::endl <<"X" &item;
        item.prev = (*start).prev;
        (*item.prev).next = &item;
        item.next = start;
        (*start).prev = &item;

    }
    start = &item;
}
```

My main() function looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    using namespace std;

    // List is empty at the beginning.
    ListItem* start = nullptr;

    printList(start);

    // This doesn't work:
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        ListItem a = createItem(i);
        addBeg(start, a);
        i++;
    }

    // This works:
    addBeg(start, createItem(12));
    addBeg(start, createItem(13));
    addBeg(start, createItem(-42));
    addBeg(start, createItem(1));
    addBeg(start, createItem(-85));

    printList(start);

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot seem to graps why it doesn't work. One reason I have thought of is that *ListItem a* does not reset in each iteration, but that does not make any sense whatsoever to me. Any help or idea is appreciated.

Comment: Linked lists work with *pointers*. In the loop you are adding the address of a locally scoped variable, and that address will not be valid outside the scope of that loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: I am not adding the address - createItem returns a ListItem object. But even if I was, why is it that it works just fine in a single addBeg() statement (shown below the loop)? What is getting done differently in the for loop?

Comment: @KristiánLeško um, yes you are. `&item` in `addBeg` gets the *address* of the referenced object. The scope of `a` is limited to the for loop, and the `a` will be destructed at the end *of each loop*.

Comment: But you *do* add the address, what do you think the ampersand `&` does in e.g. `&item`? It returns the *address* to where `item` is, and it `item` is a temporary variable that will disappear then you have problems.

Comment: OK, I have noticed a solution in Joachim's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createItem` function returns *by value*, and when passing that along directly to another function (like you do with e.g. `addBeg(start, createItem(12))` the returned value is ***temporary***. Taking and saving an address of a temporary value will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The simple solution is to have `createItem` create a node *dynamically* of the heap using `new`, and return a pointer.

Comment: Should *createItem* return a ListItem object, as is specified in its definition?

Also, if you are right, I do not know why the error you mention only demonstrates when adding items via a for loop. The single line addBeg(...) you quote works just fine.

Comment: @KristiánLeško One problem with undefined behavior is that sometimes it might *seem* to work, in reality is really doesn't. Undefined behavior makes your whole program ill-formed.